# Conflict between Smartclient classes and webservice classes

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-4.5, smartclient

I have created smartliclient and webservices.
I have created server with webservices + related classes AND client with desktop application.
In smartclient project, namespace and class name is same as there in servver-webservices.
Issue in client project-

```
using SmartInstitute.Automation.SmartInstituteServices.CourseService; // webservice
CourseService service = new CourseService();
SmartInstitute.Course[] allCourses = service.GetAllCourses();
```

SmartInstitute.Course - is present in smartClient project.
Its showing foll. error -

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'SmartInstitute.Automation.SmartInstituteServices.CourseService.Course[]'
>   to 'SmartInstitute.Course[]'

Please let me know if you want more information.
I am referring to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11163/Developing-Next-Generation-Smart-Clients-using-NET

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the namespace is **not** the same; in one, it is quite clearly `SmartInstitute.Automation.SmartInstituteServices.CourseService`, vs `SmartInstitute`. If this is a WCF service, then when you add the service there is an option in the IDE and command-line tools to re-use existing types - you *must* ensure this is enabled, and that the assembly which declares the types is specified. However, the easiest way to get this working is to have the DTO types (`Cource`, etc) in a dedicated simple assembly that is referenced and used by both tiers - then it usually "just works" - with WCF, at least. If you use 2.0-style asmx web-services, then : it will never work (it doesn't support this scenario).

The other alternative is: treat the web-service proxy types as exactly that : a DTO type that is unrelated to your main domain model. Then *map* the data between the DTO types and your domain model (there are some tools like AutoMapper that can help with this, but honestly: it is only a few lines of code to do it manually). Then the proxy types only go as far as the code that encapsulates the web-service (you are encapsulating this, yes?).